# How do I tell if a QIcon lacks a valid pixmap?

Tags: qt, qt5

If I create a [QIcon](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qicon.html) with a pixmap as in the following code snippet:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
icon = QtGui.QIcon(':/images/view-refresh.png')
```

How do I tell if the icon doesn't have a valid pixmap, e.g. because `':/images/view-refresh.png'` wasn't found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution is to wrap the QIcon constructor in a factory function that creates an explicit QPixmap, which is probed to see if it is valid:

```
def create_icon(filename):
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(filename)
    if pixmap.isNull():
        raise ValueError('No icon with filename \'{}\' found'.format(filename))
    return QtGui.QIcon(pixmap)

icon = create_icon(':/images/view-refresh.png')
```

Note that there is also a [QIcon.isNull](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qicon.html#isNull) method, but according to the documentation it can be false even if the pixmap is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `Icon.isNull()` specifically says it returns false only if it has neither a pixmap nor a filename.

Looking through the list of member functions, `availableSizes()` looks like a better candidate.  Ive tested this.

So good test to see if an icon is valid is `len(icon.availableSizes())>0`.